# iOS: Enforce a user to enter a valid IP Address while typing in TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a TextField for IP Address. Currently I am validating my IP Address on click of a button like this:

```
- (IBAction)addPrinter:(id)sender {

     NSString* validIPRegEx = @"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\\.){3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$";
     NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
                                  regularExpressionWithPattern:validIPRegEx
                                  options:0
                                  error:nil];
     NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:_printerIPAddress.text options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [_printerIPAddress.text length])];
    if (numberOfMatches!=1) {
        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Invalid IP Address"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [myAlertView show];
    }
}
```

But, my requirement is that I validate my IP Address on the go as user is entering text in TextField.

For example when user start typing in the TextField he should be allowed to enter a number between **0-255** before any of the three dot in an IP Address i.e if user has already typed 26 then the text shouldn't change if he types anything except a dot. Similarly the text should not change if he types any other character except numbers and dot.

I have searched a lot about this but found no help. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, try [`^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){0,3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xQ2xZ2/1).

Comment: My issue is not with the regular expression, it is with how I can validate partially typed IP Address every time the user types something in TextField.

Comment: I know, did you try my regex for checking that? I should mention that you cannot use one and the same regex both for *live* and *final* validation. It is impossible.

Comment: @stribizhev, I tried your regex, but it is not giving me the desired result. For ex. it failed for string 100 which is a partially valid IP Address.

Comment: [It does not choke on `100`](https://regex101.com/r/xQ2xZ2/2).

Comment: Is my way of comparing string with regex correct? Because I checked once again it is giving `numberOfMatches` as 0 for string 100.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96248/discussion-between-exception-and-stribizhev).

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. I guess you'd better use `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES`. See [this demo of your current regex](https://ideone.com/mV8EIN). You may insert my regex there and see how the behavior changes.

Comment: It will give yes for 100.100.100.100, but just for 100 it is giving no.

Comment: [It works alright](http://ideone.com/Az4ndM).

Comment: In the earlier demo you shared, the regex was wrong. I didn't realise that. Anyway it is working now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
 ............
}
```

Above this method will tell you when ever the user hits a key to change the text, a "paste" will cause multiple characters to be in the string, backspace over one, or delete of a selection will cause the string to be empty,

In this you can check the range of character 0-255.

Original answer is below.

[Detecting whether the user has typed in a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6700621/detecting-whether-the-user-has-typed-in-a-uitextfield)

Answer (score 0):

The complete answer is a combination of comments from **stribizhev** and **Muhammad's** answer. The above functionality can be implemented in the following way:

1. Make your ViewController **UITextFieldDelegate** by adding `_textfiled.delegate=self;`
2. Implement `-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string` in the following way:

   ```
   -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

       NSString* ipEntered;
       if (![string isEqualToString:@""]) {

           ipEntered=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[textfield.text substringToIndex: range.location],string];
       }

       NSString* validIPRegEx = @"^(([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[.]){0,3}([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])?$";
       NSPredicate * emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", validIPRegEx];
       if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {

           return YES;
       }
       else if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:ipEntered]){

           return YES;

       }
       else{

           return NO;
       }


   }
   ```